# A Chrome extension similar to Stylebot with built-in Less/SCSS processing?

Tags: chrome, css

I'm looking for a Chrome extension similar to [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha), but with built-in Less/SCSS processing?

Stylebot can add CSS-styling to web pages. It has an Edit CSS-feature where one can edit plain CSS.

However, I would like a similar tool taking advantage of some of the features of CSS preprocessors like Less or SCSS, that is, where I can write in those preprocessor styles and get compiled CSS injected into the page like Stylebot.

More specifically I need:

- Nesting of CSS (Less/SCSS) rules (for terser rules)
- Variables for e.g. colors and border styles (to avoid duplication/for easy global styling adjustments)